# Prove that the sum is positive

Tags: calculus

Sorry about the vague question title, I'm not sure how to phrase it.

https://autarkaw.org/2012/09/03/prove-that-the-general-least-squares-model-gives-the-absolute-minimum-of-the-sum-of-the-squares-of-the-residuals/

if you have a look at this solution in the link, there is an equation numbered 13 about half way down. It is a crucial part of the solution but the write didn't write the proof for it.

I asked for the solution before and this was provided, thank you StackExchange! But at the time I didn't notice this part was missing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes that's true, but the issue is we haven't learned the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, so I can't use it. Is there any other way to prove it? Would it be realistic if I copied the proof for the Cauchy-Schwarz and said I did it? seems a bit too much for a college student

Comment: I don't really care about your opinion on the matter. No offence intended but a lot of people like you tend to give unsolicited advice on things that don't concern you.  

 If you must know, I can't ask him that because we haven't DONE C-S, so if I ask him he will know I've been looking stuff up on the internet, which is not what he wants me to do.